# Are woven geotextile fabric really permeable?

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover, landscape-fabric

I plan to build a garden path covered with pine barks. To prevent weeds there should be some kind of ground cover under the barks, and this cover must be water permeable. I bought a woven geotextile fabric (polypropylene), described by the vendor as providing *good permeability*. After seeing the fabric I had doubts about its permeability: I tested it by pouring water on the fabric and check if the water ends in a plate I've placed underneath. At first the fabric seems perfectly waterproof, and there's no change for hours:

[image: Water permeability test]

The water went completely through about 20 hours afterwards.

The question is: how can the vendor consider that the fabric is water permeable if the water doesn't go through for so long ? Under heavy rain we should expect the water to go through directly instead of stagnate for hours, shouldn't we ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I can finally answer my own question. The reason was that the fabric was closely folded then rolled for the packaging, and when I unrolled the fabric for the permeability test I hadn't seen that I actually poured water on two layers of the fabric stuck together. The permeability is ok with the test on one layer.

I feel kind of stupid. Case closed.

Comment: We live and learn. I wish I had a pound for every time I felt stupid :-)